# How to move camera in x-z axis only RTS touch for mobile?

Tags: ios, camera, unity-game-engine, perspectivecamera

I am working on RTS based game for mobile. I want to control camera just like "Clash of Clan", I found a tutorial and script by Savalish on youtube. But that was for 2D game. I want that result in 3D so i modified it. Everything is working fine except the camera is moving upward direction that is y-axis. I don't want that. and also need boundaries for limiting camera to move further. Below is the code I used:

```
using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;



    public class TouchCameraControl : MonoBehaviour 
     {

    public float moveSensitivityX = 1.0f;
         public float moveSensitivityY = 1.0f;
         public bool updateZoomSensitivity = true;
         public float orthoZoomSpeed = 0.05f;
         public float minZoom = 1.0f;
         public float maxZoom = 20.0f;
         public bool invertMoveX = false;
         public bool invertMoveY = false;
         public float mapWidth = 60.0f;
         public float mapHeight = 40.0f;

         public float inertiaDuration = 1.0f;

         private Camera _camera;

         private float minX, maxX, minY, maxY;
         private float horizontalExtent, verticalExtent;

         private float scrollVelocity = 0.0f;
         private float timeTouchPhaseEnded;
         private Vector3 scrollDirection = Vector3.zero;

         void Start () 
         {
             _camera = Camera.main;

             maxZoom = 0.5f * (mapWidth / _camera.aspect);

             if (mapWidth > mapHeight)
                 maxZoom = 0.5f * mapHeight;

             if (_camera.fieldOfView > maxZoom)
                 _camera.fieldOfView = maxZoom;

             CalculateLevelBounds ();
         }

         void Update () 
         {
             if (updateZoomSensitivity)
             {
                 moveSensitivityX = _camera.fieldOfView / 5.0f;
                 moveSensitivityY = _camera.fieldOfView / 5.0f;
             }

             Touch[] touches = Input.touches;

             if (touches.Length < 1)
             {
                 //if the camera is currently scrolling
                 if (scrollVelocity != 0.0f)
                 {
                     //slow down over time
                     float t = (Time.time - timeTouchPhaseEnded) / inertiaDuration;
                     float frameVelocity = Mathf.Lerp (scrollVelocity, 0.0f, t);
                     _camera.transform.position += -(Vector3)scrollDirection.normalized * (frameVelocity * 0.05f) * Time.deltaTime;

                     if (t >= 1.0f)
                         scrollVelocity = 0.0f;
                 }
             }

             if (touches.Length > 0)
             {
                 //Single touch (move)
                 if (touches.Length == 1)
                 {
                     if (touches[0].phase == TouchPhase.Began)
                     {
                         scrollVelocity = 0.0f;
                     }
                     else if (touches[0].phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
                     {
                         Vector3 delta = touches[0].deltaPosition;

                         float positionX = delta.x * moveSensitivityX * Time.deltaTime;
                         positionX = invertMoveX ? positionX : positionX * -1;

                         float positionY = delta.y * moveSensitivityY * Time.deltaTime;
                         positionY = invertMoveY ? positionY : positionY * -1;

                         _camera.transform.position += new Vector3 (positionX, 0, positionY);
                         //_camera.transform.position += transform.TransformDirection((Vector2)((new Vector2 (positionX, positionY-positionX))));
                         scrollDirection = touches[0].deltaPosition.normalized;
                         scrollVelocity = touches[0].deltaPosition.magnitude / touches[0].deltaTime;


                         if (scrollVelocity <= 100)
                             scrollVelocity = 0;
                     }
                     else if (touches[0].phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
                     {
                         timeTouchPhaseEnded = Time.time;
                     }
                 }


                 //Double touch (zoom)
                 if (touches.Length == 2)
                 {
                     Debug.Log ("Double Touch");
                     Vector2 cameraViewsize = new Vector2 (_camera.pixelWidth, _camera.pixelHeight);

                     Touch touchOne = touches[0];
                     Touch touchTwo = touches[1];

                     Vector2 touchOnePrevPos = touchOne.position - touchOne.deltaPosition;
                     Vector2 touchTwoPrevPos = touchTwo.position - touchTwo.deltaPosition;

                     float prevTouchDeltaMag = (touchOnePrevPos - touchTwoPrevPos).magnitude;
                     float touchDeltaMag = (touchOne.position - touchTwo.position).magnitude;

                     float deltaMagDiff = prevTouchDeltaMag - touchDeltaMag;

                     _camera.transform.position += _camera.transform.TransformDirection ((touchOnePrevPos + touchTwoPrevPos - cameraViewsize) * _camera.fieldOfView / cameraViewsize.y);

                     _camera.fieldOfView += deltaMagDiff * orthoZoomSpeed;
                     _camera.fieldOfView = Mathf.Clamp (_camera.fieldOfView, minZoom, maxZoom) - 0.001f;

                     _camera.transform.position -= _camera.transform.TransformDirection ((touchOne.position + touchTwo.position - cameraViewsize) * _camera.fieldOfView / cameraViewsize.y);

                     CalculateLevelBounds ();
                 }
             }
         }

         void CalculateLevelBounds ()
         {
             verticalExtent = _camera.fieldOfView;
             horizontalExtent = _camera.fieldOfView * Screen.width / Screen.height;
             minX = horizontalExtent - mapWidth / 2.0f;
             maxX = mapWidth / 2.0f - horizontalExtent;
             minY = verticalExtent - mapHeight / 2.0f;
             maxY = mapHeight / 2.0f - verticalExtent;
         }

         void LateUpdate ()
         {
             //Vector3 limitedCameraPosition = _camera.transform.position;
             //limitedCameraPosition.x = Mathf.Clamp (limitedCameraPosition.x, minX, maxX);
             //limitedCameraPosition.y = Mathf.Clamp (limitedCameraPosition.y, minY, maxY);
             //_camera.transform.position = limitedCameraPosition;
         }

         void OnDrawGizmos ()
         {
             //Gizmos.DrawWireCube (Vector3.zero, new Vector3 (mapWidth, mapHeight, 0));
         }
     }
```

Tell me please what is wrong with the code. Any help would appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Set your Camera at (90,0,0).
- Replace the line

`_camera.transform.position += new Vector3 (positionX, 0, positionY);`

with

```
//For perspective Camera
    _camera.transform.position += new Vector3 (positionX+positionY, 0, positionY-positionX);

//For orthographic Camera
_camera.transform.position += new Vector3 (positionX, 0, positionY);
```

It should work now. I have tested on an empty project.

Answer (score 0):

Get and store the original Y-axis value of the camera in the Start() function then use it to modify the camera's y-axis each time before any code that modifies the position of the camera like:

`_camera.transform.position` `=` or `-=` or `+=`

**Create Variable to Store Camera Y Position**

```
float yCamPos;
```

**Init the yCamPos in the `Start()` function**

```
yCamPos = _camera.transform.position.y;
```

**Overwriting the Camera Y-axis**:

**1**.Change  `_camera.transform.position += new Vector3(positionX, 0, positionY);` inside your `Update()` function to

```
_camera.transform.position += new Vector3(positionX, yCamPos, positionY);
```

**2**.Change   `_camera.transform.position += _camera.transform.TransformDirection((touchOnePrevPos + touchTwoPrevPos - cameraViewsize) * _camera.fieldOfView / cameraViewsize.y);`

to

```
Vector3 tempVector1 = (touchOnePrevPos + touchTwoPrevPos - cameraViewsize) * _camera.fieldOfView / cameraViewsize.y;
tempVector1.y = yCamPos; //Overwrite the y axis
_camera.transform.position +=_camera.transform.TransformDirection(tempVector1);
```

**3**.Change `_camera.transform.position -= _camera.transform.TransformDirection((touchOne.position + touchTwo.position - cameraViewsize) * _camera.fieldOfView / cameraViewsize.y);`

to

```
Vector3 tempVector2 = (touchOne.position + touchTwo.position - cameraViewsize) * _camera.fieldOfView / cameraViewsize.y;
tempVector2.y = yCamPos; //Overwrite the y axis
_camera.transform.position -= _camera.transform.TransformDirection(tempVector2);
```

**Overwriting the scrollDirection Y-axis**:

**1**.Change

```
_camera.transform.position += -(Vector3)scrollDirection.normalized * (frameVelocity * 0.05f) * Time.deltaTime;
```

to

```
Vector3 sDir1 = (Vector3)scrollDirection.normalized * (frameVelocity * 0.05f) * Time.deltaTime;
sDir1.y = yCamPos;  //Overwrite the y axis
_camera.transform.position += -sDir1;
```

**The whole code**:

```
public class TouchCameraControl : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float moveSensitivityX = 1.0f;
    public float moveSensitivityY = 1.0f;
    public bool updateZoomSensitivity = true;
    public float orthoZoomSpeed = 0.05f;
    public float minZoom = 1.0f;
    public float maxZoom = 20.0f;
    public bool invertMoveX = false;
    public bool invertMoveY = false;
    public float mapWidth = 60.0f;
    public float mapHeight = 40.0f;

    public float inertiaDuration = 1.0f;

    private Camera _camera;

    private float minX, maxX, minY, maxY;
    private float horizontalExtent, verticalExtent;

    private float scrollVelocity = 0.0f;
    private float timeTouchPhaseEnded;
    private Vector3 scrollDirection = Vector3.zero;

    //Get Original Camera Y Position
    float yCamPos = 0f;

    void Start()
    {
        _camera = Camera.main;

        //Init the yCamPos
        yCamPos = _camera.transform.position.y;


        maxZoom = 0.5f * (mapWidth / _camera.aspect);

        if (mapWidth > mapHeight)
            maxZoom = 0.5f * mapHeight;

        if (_camera.fieldOfView > maxZoom)
            _camera.fieldOfView = maxZoom;

        CalculateLevelBounds();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (updateZoomSensitivity)
        {
            moveSensitivityX = _camera.fieldOfView / 5.0f;
            moveSensitivityY = _camera.fieldOfView / 5.0f;
        }

        Touch[] touches = Input.touches;

        if (touches.Length < 1)
        {
            //if the camera is currently scrolling
            if (scrollVelocity != 0.0f)
            {
                //slow down over time
                float t = (Time.time - timeTouchPhaseEnded) / inertiaDuration;
                float frameVelocity = Mathf.Lerp(scrollVelocity, 0.0f, t);

                Vector3 sDir1 = (Vector3)scrollDirection.normalized * (frameVelocity * 0.05f) * Time.deltaTime;
                sDir1.y = yCamPos;  //Overwrite the y axis
                _camera.transform.position += -sDir1;

                if (t >= 1.0f)
                    scrollVelocity = 0.0f;
            }
        }

        if (touches.Length > 0)
        {
            //Single touch (move)
            if (touches.Length == 1)
            {
                if (touches[0].phase == TouchPhase.Began)
                {
                    scrollVelocity = 0.0f;
                }
                else if (touches[0].phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
                {
                    Vector3 delta = touches[0].deltaPosition;

                    float positionX = delta.x * moveSensitivityX * Time.deltaTime;
                    positionX = invertMoveX ? positionX : positionX * -1;

                    float positionY = delta.y * moveSensitivityY * Time.deltaTime;
                    positionY = invertMoveY ? positionY : positionY * -1;

                    //Overwrite the y axis
                    _camera.transform.position += new Vector3(positionX, yCamPos, positionY);


                    //_camera.transform.position += transform.TransformDirection((Vector2)((new Vector2 (positionX, positionY-positionX))));
                    scrollDirection = touches[0].deltaPosition.normalized;
                    scrollVelocity = touches[0].deltaPosition.magnitude / touches[0].deltaTime;


                    if (scrollVelocity <= 100)
                        scrollVelocity = 0;
                }
                else if (touches[0].phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
                {
                    timeTouchPhaseEnded = Time.time;
                }
            }


            //Double touch (zoom)
            if (touches.Length == 2)
            {
                Debug.Log("Double Touch");
                Vector2 cameraViewsize = new Vector2(_camera.pixelWidth, _camera.pixelHeight);

                Touch touchOne = touches[0];
                Touch touchTwo = touches[1];

                Vector2 touchOnePrevPos = touchOne.position - touchOne.deltaPosition;
                Vector2 touchTwoPrevPos = touchTwo.position - touchTwo.deltaPosition;

                float prevTouchDeltaMag = (touchOnePrevPos - touchTwoPrevPos).magnitude;
                float touchDeltaMag = (touchOne.position - touchTwo.position).magnitude;

                float deltaMagDiff = prevTouchDeltaMag - touchDeltaMag;

                Vector3 tempVector1 = (touchOnePrevPos + touchTwoPrevPos - cameraViewsize) * _camera.fieldOfView / cameraViewsize.y;
                tempVector1.y = yCamPos; //Overwrite the y axis
                _camera.transform.position += _camera.transform.TransformDirection(tempVector1);

                _camera.fieldOfView += deltaMagDiff * orthoZoomSpeed;
                _camera.fieldOfView = Mathf.Clamp(_camera.fieldOfView, minZoom, maxZoom) - 0.001f;

                Vector3 tempVector2 = (touchOne.position + touchTwo.position - cameraViewsize) * _camera.fieldOfView / cameraViewsize.y;
                tempVector2.y = yCamPos; //Overwrite the y axis
                _camera.transform.position -= _camera.transform.TransformDirection(tempVector2);

                CalculateLevelBounds();
            }
        }
    }

    void CalculateLevelBounds()
    {
        verticalExtent = _camera.fieldOfView;
        horizontalExtent = _camera.fieldOfView * Screen.width / Screen.height;
        minX = horizontalExtent - mapWidth / 2.0f;
        maxX = mapWidth / 2.0f - horizontalExtent;
        minY = verticalExtent - mapHeight / 2.0f;
        maxY = mapHeight / 2.0f - verticalExtent;
    }

    void LateUpdate()
    {
        //Vector3 limitedCameraPosition = _camera.transform.position;
        //limitedCameraPosition.x = Mathf.Clamp (limitedCameraPosition.x, minX, maxX);
        //limitedCameraPosition.y = Mathf.Clamp (limitedCameraPosition.y, minY, maxY);
        //_camera.transform.position = limitedCameraPosition;
    }

    void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        //Gizmos.DrawWireCube (Vector3.zero, new Vector3 (mapWidth, mapHeight, 0));
    }
}
```

Code was not tested because I do not have the graphic files but it is expected to work....

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I understood the logic you explained. The explanation is very helpful. But somehow its not working. The Y-axis increase too much when I scroll to move.